# Apache 2 DNS redirects to internal IP

Tags: dns, webserver, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

> Ubuntu 18.04 && Apache 2.4.29

Installed LAMP and WordPress and I can access trough `192.168.1.80`.

Already opened port 80 on router and checked it on [here](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/).

> This is my Apache2 Site Configuration :

(Replaced xx with my actual DNS)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin xx.ddns.net 
    ServerName xx.ddns.net
    ServerAlias www.xx.ddns.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

> Checking if Ubuntu is listening :

```
root@ubuntudiogo:~# sudo iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 479 packets, 42264 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   79 15269 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 402 packets, 55621 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

> Locally everything works fine. When I try to access it trough external
>   network (In this case my phone via 4G) the page redirects to my
>   internal IP.

Can't find solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your server Alias needs to be changed to

```
ServerName  xx.ddns.net   
ServerAlias xx.ddns.net
```